# How to include fonts globally with Styled-Components in React App

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to use createGlobalStyles in styled-components to use fonts globally within my React App. However when adding GlobalStyles to app.js, the fonts aren't loading at all.

fonts.js
`

```
import {createGlobalStyle} from 'styled-components';
import Chonburi from './Chonburi.ttf';
import PlayfairDisplayBold from './PlayfairDisplayBold.woff';


export default createGlobalStyle`
    @font-face {
        font-family:"Chonburi";
        url:(${Chonburi}) format('truetype');
        font-weight:bold;
        font-style:normal;
    }

    *{
       
        font-family:'Chonburi';
    }

`;
```

App.js

```
  <>
      <GlobalFonts />
      <Typography size='40px' family='Chonburi' >hey there</Typography>
  
    </>
```

Comment: Are you using material UI?

Comment: No , I'm using styled-components

Comment: Try `src:(${Chonburi})` and remove url

Comment: I tried using src:url(${Choburi)) which ended up working..but then it stopped working shortly after.

Comment: Show your `Typography` component ??